# Unity/C# what's wrong with the way I think about this problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, architecture

I have an abstract parent class called Item
From this I inherent to Equipment and from here to Weapon and Armor. Since I want my weapons to have varying  behavior, I want my logic to operate on the classes. From my Item class I also inherit to a Resource class, which should be static. My Equipment class shouldn't and should be instansiable , since an individual sword eg. Can be sharpened or damaged, to change it from its base class without changing all other swords. So I need to clone these class instances. But since cloning a class is a very non forward thing to do, I was wondering if I am doing something wrong in my architecture, and thinking about the problem in the wrong way? Do anyone have any thoughts? /Mikael

Comment: I think it would be nice if you could add some code. I don't want to visualise this in my head.

Comment: Please post your / a code to "visualize" what you mean. As already mentioned before it is pretty hard to imagine what you are actually trying to achieve. Sounds a bit like you might be interested in using [ScriptableObjects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html)

Comment: The thing is, its not a code issue but a general approach one, but maybe I should write some pseudo code to base my question one and to refer to for discussion

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider setting the 'stats' for items in a file (xml or such) and then create a Factory class that can give you a file with all the stats already set.

i.e.

```
   public abstract ItemFactory{
     public static Sword GetSword(){
       var sword = new Sword();
       //Set stats for sword from file
       return sword;
     }
   }
```

Comment: I thought about that as well, have a class that represents the behavior, and then import all the stat variating instances from Json or something

Answer (score 0):

Why use cloning when you can just use referencing? If I understand your problem correctly, I would utilize [ScriptableObjects](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) for defining your item objects, which makes them Assets in your project. Which then can be assigned via the inspector.
The general class layout could look something like this.

```
class Equipment : ScriptableObject
{
    public int goldCost;
}

class Weapon : Equipment
{
    public intDefaultSharpness;
}
```

These are your definition classes, remember they are to define the general properties of each item category. So you might have a Sword, but not a "Broadsword of fiery Dragonkiller". If you check the link about `ScriptableObjects` you will find code that allows you to instantiate new Assets from these definition classes. Now you can create your Broadsword and ofc many more. Now your objects just become assets like Textures and 3D models. You can easily edit them in the inspector (and probably want it to make it even nicer with custom editors)

Similar to a texture or 3D Model we don't copy it every time we use it, instead we reference it. So when your player character holds a weapon you have a sub `GameObject` that just keeps a reference to the original object and any additional "local" data.

```
class PlayerWeapon : GameObject
{
    public Weapon template;
    public int durability;
}
```

The nice thing is, the `template` Weapon is assignable via inspector in the editor, as it is just a normal asset. And the `durability` property is local to this playerWeapon and the `GameObject` could be used multiple times.

Of course, this can be expanded on as much as you want. I would probably add getter/setter to hide additional calculation based on buffs/debuffs. Something like

```
public int AttackStrength
{
    get 
    {
        return owner.strength + template.strength
    }
}
```

Comment: It was actually my first idea to use scriptable objects as templates for items, with varying instances of these templates, mostly since all tutorials and guides on such systems, tends to use this approach. However I just thought it to scale bad, as I feared constantly creating and destroying assets would be somewhat troublesome

Comment: You shouldn't be constantly creating and destroying assets. Assets are files that are part of your project - the things in your project window. You create instances, just like you would with any `Monobehaviour`. The ScriptableObjects are usually just used to hold configuration information that doesn't change.

Comment: You are not creating assets, you are referencing them. If you have an Item as an asset, your use a Proxy object, like a gameobject, to reference it and additionally store any "modifications" like durability or buffs etc.